# angularjs $http json status code -1 404

Tags: php, angularjs, json

I have a php file returning json data with a json header

```
<?php
header('Content-type: application/json;charset=UTF-8');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache');
header('Content-Encoding: gzip');
header('Content-Language: en');
header('Pragma: no-cache');
header('Connection: keep-alive');

echo file_get_contents('url');
?>
```

The php file link is: http://champtechnet.com/mta/get311.php

I've tested my link in browser, and shows the json data however in angularjs it fails every time. I've used angularjs $http service many times before and is currently using it..

Please use this plunker link to help me: http://plnkr.co/edit/QzkXeCWpUe9wA8dB9W15?p=preview

```
(function(angular) {
  'use strict';
  angular.module('httpExample', [])
    .controller('FetchController', ['$scope', '$http', '$templateCache',
  function($scope, $http, $templateCache) {
    $scope.method = 'GET';
    $scope.url = 'http://champtechnet.com/mta/get311.php';

    $scope.fetch = function() {
      $scope.code = null;
      $scope.response = null;

      $http({
        method: $scope.method,
        url: $scope.url,
        cache: $templateCache
      }).
      then(function(response) {
        $scope.status = response.status;
        $scope.data = response.data;
      }, function(response) {
        $scope.data = response.data || "Request failed";
        $scope.status = response.status;
      });
    };
  }
]);
})(window.angular);
```

Comment: Try to remove this `header('Content-Encoding: gzip');`

Comment: Thank you @rashad-ibrahimov !
It works!